# ambiguous overload with ostream

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm stuck with this why trying to overlap ostream of std::array in c++.
(error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream'} and 'const char [2]')
here is my script:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, T& arr)
{
    bool pre = false;
    for(auto& i : arr)
    {
        if(pre) out << ' ';
        pre = true;
        out << i;
    }
    return out;
}

signed main()
{
    array<int, 4> a = {123, 123, 12, 12};
    cout << a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error is pointing to `<< "\n"` part. I guess you need to `#include <iostream>`

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work

Comment: You have provided `operator<<` that accepts anything at all. This makes it ambiguous with all the standard library overloads of `operator<<`

Comment: do we have any alternative measure to deal with this problem ?

Comment: A rule of thumb is that any operators you overload must have at least one type you own as a parameter. Overloading operators purely for `std::` types and/or builtin types is a bad idea.

Comment: Figure out how to use `std::enable_if` to disable this overload for `char*` type (and probably also `std::string` type).

Comment: Alternatively, make a template for `std::array` specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This forces the overload to take only `std::array`, which should solve your ambiguous overload problem:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const std::array<T, N> &arr)
{
    bool pre = false;
    for(auto& i : arr)
    {
        if(pre) out << ' ';
        pre = true;
        out << i;
    }
    return out;
}
```